# simple question about preg_match() in php

Tags: php

i used bellow code to search and find if http is includes in $url address user enters

```
if (!preg_match("/http:///", $user_website)
```

but i got this error

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '/' in
```

i know its becuase of // of http  but how work arround this !?

Comment: whats with the preg_match nonsense? there is a built-in function in php just for that: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: thanks for your note, but i just wondering about how to work around that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having to escape every `/` in URL regexes it's often useful to use `preg_*` alternative characters to mark the start/end of the pattern.

```
if (!preg_match("#http://#", $user_website)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the slashes like the other answers mention, or alternatively you can use different delimiters, preferably characters you won't use in your regex:

```
preg_match('~http://~', ...)
preg_match('!http://!', ...)
```

And you don't really need regex for this. String matching should be enough:

```
if (strpos($user_website, 'http://') !== false) {
    // do something
}
```

See: [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: would've been a +1 if there already wasn't a parse_url function

Comment: @shy It doesn't seem like the OP wants to parse the URL

Comment: well, it does seem so to me :)

Answer (score 2):

The delimiter you are using `/` is found in the pattern as well. In such cases you can either ***escape the delimiter*** in the pattern:

```
if (!preg_match("/http:\/\//", $user_website)
```

or you can ***choose a different delimiter***. This will keep the pattern clean and short:

```
if (!preg_match("#http://#", $user_website)
```

Answer (score 2):

Surely you must do

```
$parts = parse_url($my_url);
```

`$parts['scheme']` will then contain the url scheme (might be 'http').

Comment: +1 for mentioning the right tool for the job.  Don't use a regex to parse a URL when there's already a perfectly good built-in!

Also, due to a missing `^`, the OP's regex would match `https://example.com/a/b/c/http://x/y/z` which is a valid-enough URL (I recently encountered a site that served content from a URL like the above)

Answer (score 1):

Escape `/` characters with `\` characters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape literal characters. Place a back-slash before your forward slashes.

`http://` becomes `http:\/\/`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!preg_match("/http:\/\//", $user_website)
```